# math of multiple range section

Tags: python, math, range

I have a problem of range math of minus.

first, I have a big range of int, let it be:

> Range_A = range(5, 21)

then, I also have multiple small ranges, let it be:

> Range_B = (range(1,4) + range(1,7) + range(10,16) + range(19,26))

finally, the problem is what Range_A left after every elements in Range_B is removed:

> Range_A - Range_B =
> range(7,10) + range(16,19)

so far so simple, but, as length of ranges can be very huge, when I tried with algorithm of checking each element in Range_A and Range_B (I use set() data structure in Python, wish it could be faster), running time still comes to be unacceptable:

> >>> A = set(range(5,21))
>
> >>> B = set.union(set(range(1,4)), set(range(1,7)), set(range(10,16)), set(range(19,26)))
>
> >>> A - B
>
> set([7,8,9,16,17,18])

```
def hug(a):
"""return start and end of continuous element from a list
[1,2,3,5,7,8,9,12] -> [[1,3],[7,9]]
return [-1,-1] if input is a empty list
"""
if not a:
    return [[-1,-1]]
a = sorted(list(set(a)))
res = []
head = a[0]; last = a[0]
for now in a[1:]:
    if now == last + 1:
        # proced
        last = now
        if now == a[-1]:
            res.append([head, last])
    else:
        #print now
        if head != last:
            res.append([head, last])
        head = now
        last = now
return res
```

> # last step
>
> >>> hug([7,8,9,16,17,18])
>
> [[7,9],[16,18]]

I thought there must be some clear ways to achieve this, just checking the start and end point of each range, not each int element in it.

Thanks! Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: @Daulton sorry for my misleading description, wish my new edit could make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Sort all range start and end points together with field `aux=+1/-1` for start or end of range.

Traverse sorted list, adding `aux` to the counter of active intervals.

When counter becomes non-zero, interval union starts

When counter becomes zero, interval union ends

Account for these empty intervals inside big "section"

Comment: looks like this is a better way to find start and end point of result range(s), without checking each element in big range. I will try to coding it. Thanks!